# Why is my custom css file, which I have linked along with the bootstrap code, is not changing the page appearance or not working?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joGn3.png)

I am trying to create a website with bootstrap, but wanted to add some css of my own.

I have made a folder and have added my html file, not named index and in the same folder is my css file, and have linked it just after the CDN line of the bootstrap code, but the css file is not working due to some reason, and I can not figure out why.

Edit: So after I put the reference link just below the CDN line of the bootstrap code, of my own custom css. It should be working and my html should get updated, but I do not see the changes. Initially I thought it is because of the different folder, but even after putting it all into the same folder the webpage is not updating.

[image: explorer screenshot]

[image: code screenshot]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you describe your problem better? What do you mean with "the css file is not working"? Is that CSS file loaded by the browser? Is there a problem with your CSS code? It would be useful to see your CSS code too.

Comment: This question needs detail.

Comment: Sure adding a picture of the css code

Comment: Please see [ask]. We don't debug images here. You wouldn't want to, either. :)

Comment: Alright. Just learning... :)

Comment: Folks please let me know if the edits help understand the issue now?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <link href="~/FolderName/Petvrs.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Or drag and drop this css file inside HTML page it's must work.